# How to take photo and save the result into Pictures on Andrdoid 10?

Tags: android, mediastore, android-10.0, scoped-storage

Google introduced Scoped Storage on Android 10, according to the document, we can write to the public directories without requesting permission by using MediaStore API.

Before Android 10, when we need to take a photo and save it to Pictures, code is like below:

```
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File
            ...
        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                                                  "com.example.android.fileprovider",
                                                  photoFile);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
        }
    }
}

String currentPhotoPath;

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
        imageFileName,  /* prefix */
        ".jpg",         /* suffix */
        storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    currentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}
```

We create the file directly in the Pictures, and put the file uri into the takePhotoIntent extra, while we start the intent and take a photo, original-size photo will be saved into the Pictures directory.

But now we are targeting android 10, according to the doc, it is not nessasary to request the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission to save a photo into the Pictures directory.

Without the  permission, we can't create the file and then get the uri of the file, put it into the intent extra. So how can we save the original-size photo?

Comment: "So how can we save the original-size photo?" -- your code is fine, if you change your `File` (and `FileProvider` XML) to a location that you can write to (e.g., `getExternalFilesDir()` on `Context`). Alternatively, at least in principle, you could use `insert()` on `MediaStore` to get a `Uri`, then pass that `Uri` via `EXTRA_OUTPUT` to the camera app.

Comment: `We create the file directly in the Pictures` Do not create an empty file there already. If the user cancels taking a picture you are left with an empty file. The only thing you need is a path to your file in the Pictures directory. The used camera app will then create the file.